# How to unset field in views conditionally

Tags: views

I'm using `hook_views_pre_render()` in a module to make sure an image field `'field_field_company_logo'` is removed for a certain content type `'job_listing'`. I have the following code, which works, but produces warnings:

```
function hideviewsfields_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  if ( ($view->name == 'job_search') && ($view->current_display == 'job_search_results') ) {
    $result = $view->result;
    foreach ($result as $row) {
      $type = $row->_field_data['nid']['entity']->type;
      if ( $type == 'job_listing' ) {
        unset ( $row->field_field_company_logo );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It works, in as much as the correct images are omitted, but I get the following warnings:

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$field_field_company_logo in views_handler_field_field->get_items() (line 715 of /public_html/sites/all/modules/views/modules/field/views_handler_field_field.inc).
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in views_handler_field->advanced_render() (line 1053 of /public_html/sites/all/modules/views/handlers/views_handler_field.inc).
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$field_field_company_logo in views_handler_field_field->get_items() (line 715 of /public_html/sites/all/modules/views/modules/field/views_handler_field_field.inc).
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in views_handler_field->advanced_render() (line 1053 of /public_html/sites/all/modules/views/handlers/views_handler_field.inc).
```

I've seen elsewhere people writing code similar to the following:

```
unset($view->field[$field_name]);
unset($view->display_handler->handlers['field'][$field_name]);
```

where the first line seems similar to the unset I am executing, but I believe it was acting upon a different variable (i.e. not $views -- maybe $data?) and I can't find any other reference to the image field within the $view object that can be unset without it removing it altogether from the display.

Comment: Try setting $row->field_field_company_logo to some empty value rather than using unset. Some rows have this value and some don't and I think that is the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drill down in the field_field_company_logo field to its ['rendered']['#access'] property and set it's value to FALSE.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you! :) Just to clarify, I removed the `unset ( $row->field_field_company_logo );` line and added `$row->field_field_company_logo[0]['rendered']['#access'] = FALSE ;`

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to hide/unset field in **Drupal 8** but the above approach was not working so I used following code to hide/unset field in Views result page (**D8**),

```
function hideviewsfields_views_pre_render(ViewExecutable $view) {
  if ($view->id() == 'job_search') {
    foreach ($view->field as $key => $value) {
      if ($key == 'field_company_rating') {
        $value->options['exclude'] = TRUE;
      }
    }
  }
}
```